# List all files with certain extension in all folders or sub folders of sdcard - android

Tags: android, android-listview

This may seem like an old question but I have tried all solutions and this doesn't seem to work for me. I use the following code for listing all files with extension .docx in my ListView. However, this doesn't work properly for some reason and lists only all files under root.

In onCreate:

```
view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    //getting SDcard root path
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    getfile(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        if(!fileList.get(i).isDirectory() & fileList.get(i).getName().endsWith(".docx") || fileList.get(i).getName().endsWith(".doc")) {
            textView.setText((i+1)+". "+fileList.get(i).getName());

            Toast.makeText(this, fileList.get(j).getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     .....
                }
            });
            view.addView(textView);
        }
        else { 
            getfile( new File(fileList.get(i).getAbsolutePath()));  // its directory so similar code but new filelist instance
            for (int k = 0; k < fileList.size(); k++) {
                //TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                if(!fileList.get(k).isDirectory() & fileList.get(k).getName().endsWith(".docx") || fileList.get(k).getName().endsWith(".doc")) {
                    textView.setText((k+1)+". "+fileList.get(i).getName());

                    Toast.makeText(this, fileList.get(j).getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                          ...
                        }
                    });
                    view.addView(textView);
                }
                else {

                }

            }
        }
```

getFile ArrayList function:

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".docx")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".doc"))
                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Is it better to just query such mimetype from MediaStore with content resolver?

Comment: Seems if you want to go down the directory tree you need to recurse here instead of doing nothing: `if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

            }`

Comment: I tried doing this `else if(fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                getfile(new File(fileList.get(i).getAbsolutePath()));
                for (int k = 0; k < fileList.size(); k++) {`. It didn't help me.